# Gamma function identity

Tags: gamma-function

Is there a known identity for the product $\Gamma(-1/4-ix)\Gamma(-1/4+ix)$? Here $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Something along the lines $\Gamma(-1/2-ix)\Gamma(-1/2+ix)=4\pi/[(1+4x^2)\cosh(\pi x)]$. Thanks much.